# Manually create JWK from (RSA) PublicKey in .net core 3.1

Tags: rsa, .net-core-3.1, jwk

Can any body help me in creating jwk from rsa public key like 
[Manually create JWK from (RSA) PublicKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323689/manually-create-jwk-from-rsa-publickey) in java.
Wanting to avoid Org.BouncyCastle or third party implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have created JWK from public key as per following. IF any one have better suggestion then please let me know

```
using (var textReader = new StringReader(o.publickey))
                            {
                                var pubkeyReader = new PemReader(textReader);
                                RsaKeyParameters KeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)pubkeyReader.ReadObject();
                                var obj = new JwksKey
                                {
                                    use = "sig",
                                    kid = o.short_code,
                                    e = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(KeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()),
                                    n = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(KeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned()),
                                    kty = "RSA",
                                    alg = "RS256"
                                };
                                objJwks.keys.Add(obj);
                            }
```

I want's couple of more thing from public key if possible instead of hardcoding it. two things are kty and alg. If it is possible then please let me know.
I have private key available at this time of generation. do let me know if i can get kty and alg from them then i will use it.
Thanks